# how can i get geomid from all unnamed subnodes

Tags: geometry

i have a problem. In tutorial you have said, "Note that each dot (.) can be substituted by any number of named or unnamed nodes". But if I use dWebotsGetBodyFromDEF(defname.), I can only get GeomID from one unnamed nodes, not all nodes. What should I do, if I want to get GeomID frome all unnamed subnodes.

Best wishes,
Thomas

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Please share a link to the tutorial you are talking about. Also, please show us what you expect, what you are getting, and what you have tried so far. Thanks for your kind cooperation.

Comment: In its current form this question can't be answered. What tutorial are you referring to? What program/library? What version of what software (ROS?).

Comment: with webots R2023b and ROS1. https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/utility-functions. It is for collision detection used physics plugin. I can only get the GeomID from first subnodes, not all.